# Насколько эффективен мой метод решения?

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода, комбинаторика, сложность

И вновь всех приветствую. Решил очередную задачу на контесте способом, который показался мне интересным. Т.к. я новичок, еще не совсем понимаю как определять О(n), поэтому прошу помощи в этом вопросе.

Собственно, вот сама задача:

> На вход программы поступает последовательность из N целых
>   положительных чисел. Рассматриваются все пары различных элементов
>   последовательности  (элементы пары не обязаны стоять в
>   последовательности рядом, порядок элементов в паре неважен). 
>   Необходимо определить количество пар, сумма чисел и разность индексов
>   которых кратна 3.

И мое решение:

```py
n = int(input())
summ = 0
r = [[0] * 3 for i in range(3)]
for i in range(n):
    s = int(input())
    r[i % 3][s % 3] += 1
print((r[0][0] * (r[0][0] - 1) + r[1][0] * (r[1][0] - 1) + r[2][0] * (r[2][0] - 1))//2 + r[0][1] * r[0][2] + r[1][1] * r[1][2] + r[2][1] * r[2][2])
```

Проверку на контесте прошла, результат - задача решена верно.

Comment: По сложности претензий нет, оптимальное решение, а вот читаемость можно подтянуть. Программы пишутся для людей, а не для компьютера. Иначе все бы до сих пор писали в машинных кодах.

Comment: @extrn, понял вас, исправлюсь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение отличное, сложность линейная от размера ввода

В цикле выполняется k*n операций, где k - константа, так что его сложность O(n)

Начальные строчки выполняются за константное время O(1), финальная тоже, итого

```
O(n + 1 + 1) = O(n)
```